# router.push changes url but doesn't redirects

Tags: next.js, next.js13, next-router

I'm having trouble with `router.push` in next js. Sometimes, when I do it, it changes the URL but do not redirects to the desire page...

I'm using `13.0.5` pages directory.

For example, I do this:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

(...)

const router = useRouter();

(...)

router.push(`/blog/${post.slug}`);
```

It's weird because sometimes works...

Comment: Please share link to minimal reproducible code

Answer (score 0):

You should change this:

```
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
```

to

```
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
```